# XML parsing to fetch the description tab

Tags: android

how i can parse the description details using xml parsing in android from giving xml

```
<item>
            <title>All India Lawyer Conference at Lucknow </title>
        <description>
<text><![CDATA[<p style="text-align: center;">]]></text>
<image>http://www.bjp.org/images/stories/kamala_2.png</image>
<text><![CDATA[
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff6600;"><span style="font-size: 24pt;"><strong>Bharatiya Janata Party</strong><strong><em><br /><br /></em></strong></span></span></p>
<span style="color: #008000;"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><span style="font-family: arial black,avant garde;">&nbsp;</span></span></span>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #008000;"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: 'arial black', 'avant garde';">All India Lawyer Conference </span></strong></span></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #008000;"><span style="font-size: 18pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: 'arial black', 'avant garde';">at Lucknow (Uttar Pradesh)</span></strong></span></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: 'arial black', 'avant garde'; color: #008000; font-size: large;"><strong><br /></strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"> </p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-family: andale mono,times;"><em><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">of</span></span></em></span></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: arial black,avant garde;"><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><span style="color: #000080;"><strong>BJP President Shri Nitin Gadkari</strong></span></span></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"> </p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>on<br /></strong></span></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">May 15, 2011 (Sunday)</span></span><br /></strong></p>]]></text>
        </description>
            <author> anurag.pathak@bjp.org (Anurag Pathak)</author>
            <pubDate>Sun, 15 May 2011 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
        </item>
```

i want the all text which shows in bold letters

my coding

```
@Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
    {
        printParseInfo("startElement:", uri, localName, qName);
        int attributesLength = attributes.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < attributesLength; i++)
        {
            printAttributeInfo(attributes, i);
        }
        currentElement = true;
        if (localName.equals("rss"))
        {
            /** Start */
            sitesList = new SitesList();
        }
    }
    /** Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name> -- </name> )*/
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException 
    {
        currentElement = false; 
        printParseInfo("endElement:  ", uri, localName, qName);
        /** set value */
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
        {
            //Log.d("title--->",currentValue);
            sitesList.setTitle(currentValue);
        }
        else
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("span"))
        {
            //Log.d("strong-->",currentValue);
            sitesList.setStrong(currentValue);
        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
        {
            //Log.d("description--->",currentValue);
            sitesList.setDescription(currentValue);
        }
        else
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("author"))
        {
            //Log.d("Author--->",currentValue);
            sitesList.setAuthor(currentValue);
        }
        else
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
        {
            //Log.d("pubDate--->",currentValue);
            sitesList.setPubDate(currentValue);
        }
        else
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("image"))
        {
            //Log.d("Image--->",currentValue);
            sitesList.setImage(currentValue);
        }
    }
    /** Called to get tag characters ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name> -- to get AndroidPeople Character ) */
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException 
    {
        if (currentElement) 
        {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            Log.d("char-->",currentValue);
            currentElement = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can i put here, when i write it shows as above text

Comment: Use the link of the xml.

Comment: i want to fetch the second text tab of description tab,

Comment: i have attached the coding part

Comment: @devang you are using `HTML` instead  of `XML`..Try to use any html parser to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an XML Parser:

1. [SAX](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/324/entry-2683-parsing-xml-in-java-part-1-sax/)
2. [DOM](http://code.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?automodule=blog&blogid=324&showentry=2689)
3. [StAX](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/324/entry-2717-parsing-xml-in-java-part-3-stax/)